# What is the correct way of pushing an object into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have been trying different methods to add simple coordinates as objects `{x:0, y:1}` into an array, and it works if I add them manually, so to speak.

But if I'm using a loop, the result defies my understanding. The resulting array has all objects that were pushed from inside the loop hold the exact same values as the last pushed object.

```
function(){
  var plot = ['south','east','north','east','north'] // user input
  let records = [ // the array, with an initial object
    {x: 0, y: 0}
  ];
  var step ={ // object to modify and copy into array
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < plot.length; i++) {
    if (plot[i] == "north"){
      step.y++;
    }
    if (plot[i] == "east"){
      step.x++;
    }
    if (plot[i] == "south"){
      step.y--;
    }
    if (plot[i] == "west"){
      step.x--;
    }
    console.log(step.x+','+step.y); // shows that the data is correctly modified
    records.push(step);
    console.log(records.length); // shows that the object was added to the array
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var newItem = records[i];
    console.log('newItem: x='+newItem.x+' y='+newItem.y);
  }
}
```

Furthermore, in the example above, the array's length is considered to be `2` even though it clearly reached `6` during the execution of the loop.

I can't tell if there's an error in logic, or my computer is playing tricks on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because the `step` variable is holding a reference to the object, not the object itself so each time you do

```
records.push(step);
```

you are appending *the same reference* to *the same object*. And in each iteration, you are modifying *the same object* using *the same reference*. This is why all of your elements in the `records` array have the same values inside. In order to fix this, you can either initialize `step` in each iteration:

```
for (var i = 0; i < plot.length; i++) {
    var step = { // object to modify and copy into array
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
    };
    if (plot[i] == "north") {
        step.y++;
    }
    if (plot[i] == "east") {
        step.x++;
    }
    if (plot[i] == "south") {
        step.y--;
    }
    if (plot[i] == "west") {
        step.x--;
    }
    console.log(step.x + ',' + step.y); // shows that the data is correctly modified
    records.push(step);
    console.log(records.length); // shows that the object was added to the array
}
```

or you can push to the array a copy of the object:

```
var step = { // object to modify and copy into array
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
};
for (var i = 0; i < plot.length; i++) {

    if (plot[i] == "north") {
        step.y++;
    }
    if (plot[i] == "east") {
        step.x++;
    }
    if (plot[i] == "south") {
        step.y--;
    }
    if (plot[i] == "west") {
        step.x--;
    }
    console.log(step.x + ',' + step.y); // shows that the data is correctly modified

    /* ---> */ records.push(Object.assign({}, step)); // copy the object

    console.log(records.length); // shows that the object was added to the array
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize `step` inside your `for` loop:

```
    var plot = ['south', 'east', 'north', 'east', 'north'] // user input
    let records = [ // the array, with an initial object
        { x: 0, y: 0 }
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < plot.length; i++) {
        var step = { // object to modify and copy into array
            x: i > 0 ? records[i-1].x : 0,
            y: i > 0 ? records[i-1].y : 0,
        };
        if (plot[i] == "north") {
            step.y++;
        }
        if (plot[i] == "east") {
            step.x++;
        }
        if (plot[i] == "south") {
            step.y--;
        }
        if (plot[i] == "west") {
            step.x--;
        }
        console.log(step.x + ',' + step.y); // shows that the data is correctly modified
        records.push(step);
        console.log(records.length); // shows that the object was added to the array
    }

    console.log(records);
```

Comment: That would defeat its purpose. I do not want to re-delcare 'step' on every iteration, as I need it to record data progressively.

Comment: @codePup13 You are right - I updated answer, now it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You could take just `x` and `y` for changing, depending on the direction an add a new object to `records`.

```js
function go() {
    var plot = ['south', 'east', 'north', 'east', 'north'],
        x = 0,
        y = 0,
        records = [{ x, y }];

    for (var i = 0; i < plot.length; i++) {
        switch (plot[i]) {
            case "north": y++; break;
            case "east":  x++; break;
            case "south": y--; break;
            case "west":  x--; break;
        }
        records.push({ x, y });
    }
    return records;
}

console.log(go());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to push a clone of `step`, otherwise the previous `step` is overwritten.

```js
function plotter(){
  var plot = ['south','east','north','east','north'] // user input
  let records = [ // the array, with an initial object
    {x: 0, y: 0}
  ];
  var step ={ // object to modify and copy into array
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < plot.length; i++) {
    if (plot[i] == "north"){
      step.y++;
    }
    if (plot[i] == "east"){
      step.x++;
    }
    if (plot[i] == "south"){
      step.y--;
    }
    if (plot[i] == "west"){
      step.x--;
    }
    console.log(step.x+','+step.y); // shows that the data is correctly modified
    var clone = Object. assign({}, step);
    records.push(clone);
    console.log(records.length); // shows that the object was added to the array
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var newItem = records[i];
    console.log('newItem: x='+newItem.x+' y='+newItem.y);
  }
}

plotter();
```